# Bootstrap grid for wide layout in responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css

I using bootstrap grid for my website.
UI design is wide and I have some problem with layout.I didn't know layout might had problem first, but after I wrote code for mobile and tablet devices I saw some problem.

I have image gallery in one of website pages and I using lightbox2 for that, I gave each `li` `margin-left:4%` .because my website is responsive I didn't use fix number of `li` for each row so my code for this part contain 1 `ul` and 12 `li` not 3 `ul` with 4 `li` in each of them. here where I face with problem ,last `li` in each row get `margin-left:4%`, and because of this margin `ul` can't fix in the center of page, In my opinion my layout is not correct and even UI is wide I have to use container or wrapper for website content.
[here](http://royayeketab.ir/library.html) is gallery page.

html code for main content part (header and footer are in separate div)

```
<div class="content row">
        <div class="head-style col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="title-pack col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="line visible-sm-block"></span>
                <span class="visible-sm-block tittle-style">کتابخانه</span>
                <!-- <span class=" pull-right line visible-sm-block"></span> -->
            </div>
            <div class="row library-info">
                <div class="library-box col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-12 ">
                        <ul>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>تراژدی تنهایی</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-2.jpg" title="Item 2 title ..." data-desc="Item 2 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-2.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>سرخ و سفید</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-3.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 3 A small, chocolate-covered candy with a hard or soft center." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-3.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-4.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 4 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-4.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>نوبت</h4>
                                        <p>10000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>تراژدی تنهایی</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-2.jpg" title="Item 2 title ..." data-desc="Item 2 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-2.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>سرخ و سفید</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-3.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 3 A small, chocolate-covered candy with a hard or soft center." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-3.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-4.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 4 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-4.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>نوبت</h4>
                                        <p>10000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>تراژدی تنهایی</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-2.jpg" title="Item 2 title ..." data-desc="Item 2 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-2.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>سرخ و سفید</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-3.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 3 A small, chocolate-covered candy with a hard or soft center." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-3.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>پاییز فصل آخر سال است</h4>
                                        <p>15000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="images/gallery1/image-4.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 4 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
                                        <img src="images/gallery1/thumb-4.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
                                        <h4>نوبت</h4>
                                        <p>10000 تومان</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                        </ul>   
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
<!-- ~~~~~~ <>< ~~~~ <><  ~~~~ <>< ~~~~~~~~ Start of sidebar part ~~~~~~ <>< ><> ~~~~~ <><  ~~ <>< ~~~~~~~~  -->            
            <div class="sidebar col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="sidebarbox ">

                    <div class=" library-category col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <h3>دسته بندی کتاب</h3>
                            <div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">زندگینامه</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">ادبیات</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">کودک و نوجوان</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">روانشناسی</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">هنر</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">علوم اجتماعی</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">اقتصاد</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">تجارت</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">مدیریت</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">گوناگون</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="library-category-option">
                                    <a href="">همه</a>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="search-sidebar col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <h3>جستوجو کتاب</h3>
                            <div class="dark">
                                <form role="search" method="get" class="wproduct-search" action="">

                                    <span><input placeholder="جستجو کتاب" type="text" class="search square"><input type="button" value="Search"></span>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="letter-news col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <h3>خبرنامه</h3>
                            <form>
                                <input type="" name="" placeholder="نام شما" >
                                <input class="input-dis" type="" name="" placeholder="ایمیل شما" >
                                <button class="send-button center-margin">ارسال</button>
                            </form>
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css code for this part

```
.content{
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.aboutus,
.news-index,
.book-library,
.head-style,
.double,
.best,
.pages{
    min-height: 230px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ourservice,
.besty,
.phisical-shop,
.library-info,
.about-us,
.writer-crit,
.gallery{
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.ourservice-box > div,
.phisical-store > div,
.library-box > div,
.about-us-box > div,
.writer-crit-box > div,
.gallery-box > div{
    min-height: 1000px;
}
.library-box{
    min-height: 1200px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar{
    min-height: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar .tab-content{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.sidebarbox{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    float: left;
}
.best-sells,
.letter-news,
.news-sidebar,
.search-sidebar{
    height: 535px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: rgba(223,221,224,0.8);
}
```

Also I added **lightbox.css** and **lihtbox.js**.
I hope to explain my problem clearly and seek some advice from you guys about the issues.

Comment: Remove float: right; from li and add > display: inline-block; 
Add style to the ul text-align:center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center list items inside a UL:

ul add> `text-align: center;`

Remove float property from li and replace with.

li add> `display: inline-block;`

> http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/3/

Comment: yes it works fine, so no problem with my layout? it doesn't need to add width to div.content ?

Comment: It looks fine over here miss, @mimi adding width: number px; and overflow: hidden; to the gallery thumbnails I would recommend. 

Because if I debug and type too much characters inside like what i have done here:

<p>15000 تومان15000 تومان15000 تومان15000 تومان</p>

The gallery breaks.

Comment: yes I have to define max-charector for each thumbnails. thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simply this Bootstrap class

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```